# GLFW window not responding

Tags: c++, opengl-es

I am working on an GLFW desktop application that uses openGL ES 2.0 instead of the normal openGL!

The code that i wrote compiles great but when i run the application i hear some weird sound coming from my laptop and after a few seconds the window of the application goes unresponsive when i close the window the sound stops!

Is it a hardware/software problem or i did something wrong?

this my main.cpp:

```
#ifndef GLFW_INCLUDE_ES2
#define GLFW_INCLUDE_ES2
#endif
#include "game.h"
#include <GLFW/glfw3.h>

int init_gl();
void shutdown_gl();
void set_main_loop();

GLFWwindow* window;

int main()
{
    if (init_gl() == GL_TRUE) {
        on_surface_created();
        on_surface_changed();
        set_main_loop();
    }
    shutdown_gl();
    return 0;
}

void shutdown_gl()
{
    glfwDestroyWindow(window);
    glfwTerminate();
}

int init_gl()
{
    const int width = 480,
         height = 800;

     if (glfwInit() != GL_TRUE) {
         return GL_FALSE;
     }

     window = glfwCreateWindow(width, height, "Simple example", NULL, NULL);

     if (!window) {
         return GL_FALSE;
     }

     glfwMakeContextCurrent(window);

     return GL_TRUE;
}

void set_main_loop()
{
    while (!glfwWindowShouldClose(window))
    {
        on_draw_frame();
        glfwSwapBuffers(window);
    }
}
```

tell me if u need the code from game.cpp!

The code is compiled on Ubuntu 14.04 using g++ with the commands:

```
g++ -I. -I../common -c main.cpp ../common/game.cpp
g++ main.o game.o -o main.exec -lglfw3 -lX11 -lXrandr -lXinerama -lXi -lXxf86vm -lXcursor -lGL -lpthread
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to call `glfwPollEvents()` in your loop, however I'm not 100% sure as the sound could be caused by the application not being vsync-d.
Reference:
http://www.glfw.org/docs/latest/quick.html

Comment: You were right i didn't call glfwPollEvents(). The application doesn't crash any more also the sound is coming because i render too many frames and glfwSwapInterval(1); stoped the sound so you were right 2 times. Thanks for the quick answer!